# Knockout: How to select an item by property name from an observableArray of objects

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am making my first steps with knockout by developing a small app that prints the information about a selected person, the problem is that I don't know exactly how to select an object from the array according to a specific property.

In my fiddle, I need to print all the information about a person that I select but also the persons names doesn't appear in the select box, it shows `[Object Object]`

What am I missing to get the results I want?

```js
var people = [{
    name: "Contact 1",
    address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD",
    tel: "0123456789",
    email: "anemail@me.com",
    type: "family"
}, {
    name: "Contact 2",
    address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD",
    tel: "0123456789",
    email: "anemail@me.com",
    type: "friend"
}, {
    name: "Contact 3",
    address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD",
    tel: "0123456789",
    email: "anemail@me.com",
    type: "friend"
}];

function ContactsViewModel(people) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(people);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ContactsViewModel(people));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
    Show me:
    <select data-bind="options: contacts"></select>
</div>
<div>
    Name: <span databind="text: name"></span><br>
    Adress: <span data-bind="text: address"></span><br>
    Tel: <span data-bind="text: tel"></span><br>
    Email: <span data-bind="text: email"></span><br>
    Type: <span data-bind="text: type"></span><br>
</div>
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VxT5Y/146/

Comment: FYI, please avoid having the code entirely on an external site. When the link breaks then this post will become useless. At least post the code *also* in the question. StackOverflow even mirrors some of the functionality of jsfiddle to allow runnable code snippets.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: Also see this update fiddle for a nicer way of dealing with the selected contact. http://jsfiddle.net/VxT5Y/168/ (@Guto's post shows an alternative method of expressing the same thing)

Comment: Oh waw! this is exactly what I am looking for, thank you again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use select optionsText data-bind property:

```
 <select data-bind="options: contacts,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   value: selectedName,
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks! that solves part of the problem, now I get the names printed properly in the select box, but how do I print the appropriate information of the selected contact?

Comment: That's it, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need a observable to get the value and use it to show in the form.

**[EDIT]**

As suggested by @Tomalak

```js
var people = [{
        name: "Contact 1",
        address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD",
        tel: "0123456789",
        email: "anemail@me.com",
        type: "family"
    }, {
        name: "Contact 2",
        address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD",
        tel: "0123456789",
        email: "anemail@me.com",
        type: "friend"
    }, {
        name: "Contact 3",
        address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD",
        tel: "0123456789",
        email: "anemail@me.com",
        type: "friend"
    }];


    function ContactsViewModel(people) {

        var self = this;
        self.contacts = ko.observableArray(people);
        self.selectedPerson = ko.observable();
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ContactsViewModel(people));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>Show me:
  <select data-bind="options: contacts, optionsText: 'name', value:selectedPerson"></select>
</p>
<!-- ko with: selectedPerson -->
Name:
<p data-bind="text:name"></p>
adress:
<p data-bind="text:address"></p>
tel:
<p data-bind="text:tel"></p>
email:
<p data-bind="text:email"></p>
type:
<p data-bind="text:type"></p>
 <!--/ko -->
```

Comment: Instead of binding to `text: selectedPerson().address`, I'd recommend to use a `with: selectedPerson` binding around the details section.